# Applying the Fubini Theorem

Tags: integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ 
f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
\frac{\mathrm{sign}(xy)}{x^2+y^2}, \ (x,y)\ne 0\\
0, \ (x,y)=0
\end{cases}$

Both iterated integrals are zero and therefore equal, but $f(x,y)$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

That $f(x,y)$ is not L-integrable was shown the following way:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f|\,\mathrm{d}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_y(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\infty$.

From this the conjecture was concluded.

But how can this be possible? We have that $\left | \int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right |\le \int_X |f|\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ which means that it is still possible that the non absolute value of the function is L-integrable.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be known: if $f$ is measurable, then:

$f$ is integrable $ \iff |f|$ is integrable.

Comment: That if $|f|$ is L-integrable then $f$ is L-integrable does not necessarily hold. It holds iff f is measurable. But in this case $f$ is measurable. Also, since I computed everything by using the R-integral, this relation must not hold at all.

Comment: O.K., you are right

Comment: It should be added, that this only holds for L-integrals. But I think I can understand everything now.